# WordPress How to sort by a custom meta key using a key inside it?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

On my WordPress site, each user has a custom meta key named `'user_details'` which is an array and has the following structure:

```
$user_details = array('age'=>10,'gender'=>'male');
```

in the following example, how can I sort users in an `ASC` order according to each user `'age'`?

```
<?php 
//get all users above 10 years
$args = array(
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'meta_key' => array(
            'key'       => 'user_details',
            'value'     => '',
            'type'      => 'CHAR',
            'compare'   => '!=',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'       => array( 'meta_key' => 'ASC' ),
); 
$users = get_users( $args );
?>
```

SO, the line
`array( 'meta_key' => 'ASC' )` does not sort the retrieved users according to `'age'`, how can I sort the retrieved users according to the age?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read what you wrote, having a hard time understanding what your trying to say.

Comment: it is difficult to explain what I want!
I need to sort users according to a key inside a custom meta key. The custom meta key is an array of data values stored as string keys.

Answer (score 0):

Power,

there are 2 options:

1) IF you store an array into the user meta VALUE (not the key) as you appear to have done, THEN you will have to query the records and then sort the array retrieved AFTER the query - lookup php array sorting functions.

2) AN alternative is to store the user details more cleanly in separate meta records eg: 
meta-key: user-age 
meta-key: user-gender

THEN you can query and sort at the same time.

If you look at how the data is stored in phpmyadmin and try to write a MYSQL query to extract that data, you will gain a better appreciation of the situation.

Comment: Please regarding your proposed option 1 could you please clarify using a simple code example for the query!

Comment: Sorry don't have time for tested examples, but if you look details up, you should be able to do something like  $users = get_users( $args );  where args as meta_key' => 'user_details';   then put the fields you want into an array.      Then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php to sort by the dimension/field you want.

Comment: Urg forgot to say the key part.    For each user, and then for each userdetails array copy the fields you want into an array with userid and any other user fields.  then do the array_multisort on the field you want to sort by